# C#.net escoger entre varias opciones dentro de una clase/método

Tags: c#, api, método

Estoy usando una API de un videojuego para diseñar una tontería de aplicación, la cosa es que la API trabaja con varios servidores, y quisiera que el usuario pudiese elegir el servidor.

El método es algo tal que así:

```
Api.GetSummonerByName(RiotSharp.Misc.Region.euw, InvocadorBox.Text);
```

Espera el servidor sobre el que actuar, y el nombre del usuario del juego, lo que pasa es que Region. (Opciones) tiene todos los servidores.

Sin embargo, no se me ocurre una forma 'limpia' de llamar a cada region según el usuario que no sea a través de un condicional por cada servidor, tal que si selecionó NA como servidor, tendría que volver a llamar a todo el método con la region.NA, cuándo lo que me gustaría sería simplemente editar la parte de "Region.(OPCIONES)".

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano! :)

Comment: Si no interpreto mal tu pregunta, lo que deberías hacer, es estudiar acerca del [Patron Abstract Factory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/bb972258.aspx), sería una muy buena práctica que lo apliques!

Comment: Hola @JuanSalvadorPortugal voy a echarle un vistazo a ver, gracias! :)

Comment: Puedes poner en un link la declaracion de esa API??? apuesto lo que quieras que region es un enumerado ;)

Comment: @gbianchi https://benfradet.github.io/RiotSharp/api/RiotSharp.Region.html Yep, aparece como enumerado, las regiones van del 0 al 11 si mal no recuerdo, pero no sé como llamarlas mediante enteros. Pobre llamando solo al entero dentro del método Api.GetSummonerByName(0 , InvocadorBox.Text); pero no funcionó.

Comment: no.. pero si es un enumerado, es convertible a entero ;) y no hay que hacer un case ni nada.. solo hay que usar ese enumerado como entrada del combo que selecciona la region, y usar el mismo enumerado en tu app.. y listo...

Comment: no encuentro esa funcion.. donde esta???

Comment: @gbianchi Tienes razón, no la veo en la documentación pero la ponian de ejemplo en el usage del github... https://github.com/BenFradet/RiotSharp , te adjunto también una imagen desde el visual studio. https://image.ibb.co/nh8gBo/c.png

Comment: @gbianchi Me vas a disuclpar, pero sigo algo perdido, ¿Que tengo que hacer en el combobox para vincularlo con los enteros enumerados del método? Gracias

Comment: depende de que tipo de vista uses, tenes que cargar el combo con ese enumerado.

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que entiendo que quieres hacer, es que no tengas que escribir `Api.GetSummonerByName(RiotSharp.Misc.Region.euw, InvocadorBox.Text);` n veces para todos los servidores?
Lo que puedes hacer es un método que reciba el servidor y retorne el `RiotSharp.Misc.Region` que va a utilizar. Algo como esto:

```
private RiotSharp.Misc.Region SeleccionaServidor(int idServidor)
        {
            switch (idServidor)
            {
                case 1: // EUW
                    return RiotSharp.Misc.Region.euw;
                case 2: // NA
                    return RiotSharp.Misc.Region.na;
                case 3: // LAN
                    return RiotSharp.Misc.Region.lan;
                case 4: // LAS
                    return RiotSharp.Misc.Region.las;
                    /*
                     * .
                     * . Agregar las Regiones necesarias
                     * .
                     */
            }
        }
```

y llamar tu método como 
`Api.GetSummonerByName(SeleccionaServidor(RegionBox.SelectedIndex+1), InvocadorBox.Text);` con ayuda de un `ComboBox` con las regiones

Answer (score 0):

```
Api.GetSummonerByName(RiotSharp.Misc.Region.euw, InvocadorBox.Text);
```

pero este método que retorna, me imagino que es un servidor por nombre

Ahora esa Api cuantos get tiene no GetSummonerAll() o algo asi,

Ahora si los parametros de busqueda tu los tienes registrados, aunque no seria una solucion muy rapida, podrias crear un ciclo que llamara a ese metodo y le pasaras los parametros por vuelta, y tu ir creando tu lista y al final mostrarlos todos.

recomiendo poner los datos que retorna esa api, y ver que si tiene mas metodos de busqueda

Comment: Es de las pocas veces que uso C#.net asique ando un poco perdido, (vengo de PHP y bueno... en cuanto a conocimientos de clases y métodos, tengo lo justo) en este caso, este método retorna un array (creo) con los datos de la cuenta, por ejemplo su nivel, su id, entre otras cosas. (No sé si será un array, porque el dato retornado al guardarlo en una variable llamas a su dato mediante otro método?) Tal que asi:

var n = Api.GetSummonerByName(RiotSharp.Misc.Region.euw, "Sharki");
console.writeln(n.level); Sigo en otro comentario.

Comment: La cosa es, la api tiene varios métodos para diferentes opciones, en cuanto a métodos que obtengan datos tiene unos cuantos (GetAlgo...), y la mayoria requieren del servidor y o el ID de usuario (int) o el nombre (string).

La cosa es esa, desconozco como podría llamar a X servidor en el método RiotSharp.Misc.Region.SERVIDOR porque 'Servidor' es ... ¿Un metodo? ¿Sub metodo? realmente no sé que nombre recibe... Espero haberme explicado, disculpad...

Comment: Omar, necesitas por el codigo   este linea que escriber var n = Api.GetSummonerByName(RiotSharp.Misc.Region.euw, "Sharki"); le estas asignando a la variable n = valor que retorna el metodo GetSummonerByName() del objeto Api, pero si pusieras el codigo aqui se resolveria mas facil, el resultado fue guardado en la variable n, por eso tu puedes decir n.lever, que quiere decir que n es el objeto y level su propiedad

Answer (score 0):

```
public list<Summoner> GetAll(List<MisParametros> lista)
{
    List<Summoner> nuevaLista = new List<Summoner>();

    foreach(var item in lista)
    {
        var sumomner = Api.GetSummonerByName(item.primerParametro, 
        introducir el código aquíitem.SegundoParametro);
        nuevaLista.add(sumomner);
    }
    return nuevaLista;
}
```

//nuevaLista = a los servidores obtenidos
//sumomner = es un servidor obtenido
//MisParametros esta debe ser una clase que tu crear debe contener los dos parametros que te pide el metodo.
//lista, es la lista de tus parametros, la cantidad de elementos en la lista son los servidores que obtendras